# Mule ESB - ConcurrentModificationException in FileMessageReceiver

Tags: java, mule

My Mule application deals with several different directories and it moves files around. I have a few file inbound endpoints and file connectors. I have situations where I have to poll different folders, process files, move them, poll again etc.

I am seeing this exception in the log:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1456)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:175)
    at org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver.poll(FileMessageReceiver.java:199)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractPollingMessageReceiver.performPoll(AbstractPollingMessageReceiver.java:216)
    at org.mule.transport.PollingReceiverWorker.poll(PollingReceiverWorker.java:80)
    at org.mule.transport.PollingReceiverWorker.run(PollingReceiverWorker.java:49)
    at org.mule.transport.TrackingWorkManager$TrackeableWork.run(TrackingWorkManager.java:267)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:286)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The exception is thrown here: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mule.transports/mule-transport-file/3.5.0/org/mule/transport/file/FileMessageReceiver.java#199

I've noticed that in this case http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mule.transports/mule-transport-file/3.5.0/org/mule/transport/file/FileMessageReceiver.java#675 the same collection object is returned every time files.isEmpty() - this is not ideal and could very well be the cause of the problem.

Now, luckily this exception is not disruptive overall, except it probably makes it skip a poll cycle and pollutes the log.

Anyone seen this before / ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the exception disappears if I change the listFiles() implementation when the list of files is empty.

```
package org.mule.transport.file;

import org.mule.api.MuleException;
import org.mule.api.construct.FlowConstruct;
import org.mule.api.endpoint.InboundEndpoint;
import org.mule.api.lifecycle.CreateException;
import org.mule.api.transport.Connector;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PatchedFileMessageReceiver extends FileMessageReceiver
{
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PatchedFileMessageReceiver.class);

    /**
     *
     * @param connector
     * @param flowConstruct
     * @param endpoint
     * @param readDir
     * @param moveDir
     * @param moveToPattern
     * @param frequency
     * @throws CreateException
     */
    public PatchedFileMessageReceiver(Connector connector, FlowConstruct flowConstruct, InboundEndpoint endpoint, String readDir, String moveDir, String moveToPattern, long frequency) throws CreateException
    {
        super(connector, flowConstruct, endpoint, readDir, moveDir, moveToPattern, frequency);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * @throws MuleException
     */
    @Override
    List<File> listFiles() throws MuleException
    {
        List<File> list = super.listFiles();

        if(list.isEmpty()) {
            log.trace("List of files is empty, I'm gonna return a new empty ArrayList");
        }

        return ( list.isEmpty() ? new ArrayList<File>() : list );
    }
}
```

And then set the custom FileMessageReceiver on the file connector like this

```
<file:connector name="source-file-connector" autoDelete="false" fileAge="1000" pollingFrequency="1000" >
    <service-overrides messageReceiver="org.mule.transport.file.PatchedFileMessageReceiver" />
</file:connector>
```

This stuff should be really fixed upstream. As a user one would expect not having to deal with this kind of problems.

Comment: Hello @Guido , I am using Mule ESB 3.9.0 and though the MULE ESB JIRA Board says that the issue is resolved in this version, I am still facing this issue. Also, the method listFiles() is neither public not protected, its default. Hence I cannot override it. What shall Id do? Please help

Answer (score 1):

A better solution than return a new list each time listFiles() is called (and there are no files) is to use CopyOnWriteArrayList for NO_FILES at http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mule.transports/mule-transport-file/3.5.0/org/mule/transport/file/FileMessageReceiver.java#64

```
private static final List<File> NO_FILES = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<File>();
```

This way you'll avoid the instance creation.

Comment: please write answer here instead of providing a link.

Comment: The answer is the line provided, the link is just for pointing where to put the code.